# How to Train and cross validation in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

Hello i am new to R,

I am doing coursera course for machine learning, I know training and cross validation on datasets for purpose of prediction in octave but how can i do that operations in R?

Comment: Your question is very broad, far too broad actually. If you have specific questions, e.g. how does this example of Octave code translate to R, that would be a much better topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linear regression:

```
> model <- lm(y ~ ., data = mydata)
> predict(model, mydata[1, ])
```

Cross validation for LM:

```
> install.packages("DAAG")   # if not already installed 
> library(DAAG)
> cv.lm(df = mydata, form.lm = formula(y ~ .))
```

Linear model (function `lm()`) is available by default in R, but other machine learning algorithms are not. For a set of the most popular ML algorithms see package [`e1071`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf).

Comment: caret is very good. Read the vignettes they are very helpful.http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Machine Learning taskview for a lot of packages which deal with ML in R. In addition, googling for "R machine learning" also gets you some good results probably. After studying that you probably have a good idea of what packages to use, especially when you already have ML experience.